# How can I identify what is causing a framerate drop new to 1.7.4 in only certain loaded chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

Without running mods or texture packs, 1.7.4 introduced periodic graphical stuttering when certain chunks are loaded. These chunks are fairly uninteresting, mostly undisturbed land with just a rail running through it. No redstone or other complexity.

How can I identify what is causing this stuttering so I can remove it?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a pretty good graphics card? Also, what is your render setting set to?

Comment: What is there in this land? Is it Jungle? Also check if you have hopper chains at [your render distance] from this point. Active hoppers can cause awful chunk reloading hiccups when at the edge of loaded chunk zone.

Comment: Worst case scenario, your world may be corrupted and the data may be slowing down the game. There is a tool you can use to fix corrupt worlds and numerous other problems that may be affecting them. There is an awesome tool out there called [Minecraft Region Fixer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/302380-minecraft-region-fixer/) that may help you solve the problem. Let us know what helps solve the issue!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you should give more ram to Java.
I also  also a problem like you. In a few places in my world, my Minecraft lagged a lot. If you just search on YouTube ''how to put more ram in Minecraft'' you will find a way to put more ram in to your Minecraft and maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Telling somebody to google how to do something isn't an answer. Also you don't even answer the question asked (albeit somewhat an XY question.)